# Movie about a woman and her young daughter; a person they know killed her in her past life

Tags: story-identification, movie

I don’t think it was a movie that made it to the big screen. Possibly lifetime movie?

I think it came out in the early 2000’s

The movie was about a woman and her young daughter maybe 10 years old or so and the daughter tells her mom that a person they know killed her in her past life. It was either that or that she just knows about this woman who was murdered many years ago, before she was even born. She also identifies the woman in pictures in one scene if I’m rembering correctly.

The goal was to bring this murderer to justice.

Important parts were that they knew the murderer. Don’t remember how they’re connected to him but he might have been some sort of doctor or family friend perhaps.

The movie shows flash back scenes occasionally to the woman who was killed (supposedly the young girl’s past life)

I believe there was a scene where the little girl confronts the man who had murdered her in her past life and tells him that she’s the one who he had killed before. Not sure what their relationship was in her past life.

Again, in her past life she was an adult.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if you'll see this, but I believe you're looking for **[The Haunting of Lisa](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113272/)**, a TV movie from 1996 starring Cheryl Ladd (though some details are a tiny bit off).

It's about a mother whose young daughter (who's about 10) starts having visions of a young blonde woman, which are somehow connected to the recent murders of young girls. And in the end the killer is indeed revealed to be someone they know (a friendly cop named Bob who's into the mom), and through the visions we do see flashbacks of the blonde woman (that took place before the daughter was born).

The slight differences are that *it's not really her past life*. The daughter (and her mom, we later learn) are a little psychic, and the blonde woman that the girl keeps seeing was not the killer's victim but actually his *mom*, who's now old and in a coma but somehow relates her thoughts to the little girl.

You can see the flashbacks that the girl sees in this clip: